# RSA cipher or TLS for chat application?

Tags: java, android, encryption, certificate

I am developing an android instant messaging application and i was wondering which is the best way to implement cryptography.
I have noticed that i can implement

SSLSocket:

```
// Load CAs from an InputStream
// (could be from a resource or ByteArrayInputStream or ...)
CertificateFactory cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
// From https://www.washington.edu/itconnect/security/ca/load-der.crt
InputStream caInput = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream("load-der.crt"));
Certificate ca;
try {
    ca = cf.generateCertificate(caInput);
    System.out.println("ca=" + ((X509Certificate) ca).getSubjectDN());
} finally {
    caInput.close();
}

// Create a KeyStore containing our trusted CAs
String keyStoreType = KeyStore.getDefaultType();
KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(keyStoreType);
keyStore.load(null, null);
keyStore.setCertificateEntry("ca", ca);

// Create a TrustManager that trusts the CAs in our KeyStore
String tmfAlgorithm = TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm();
TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(tmfAlgorithm);
tmf.init(keyStore);

// Create an SSLContext that uses our TrustManager
SSLContext context = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
context.init(null, tmf.getTrustManagers(), null);

// Tell the URLConnection to use a SocketFactory from our SSLContext
URL url = new URL("https://certs.cac.washington.edu/CAtest/");
HttpsURLConnection urlConnection =
    (HttpsURLConnection)url.openConnection();
urlConnection.setSSLSocketFactory(context.getSocketFactory());
InputStream in = urlConnection.getInputStream();
copyInputStreamToOutputStream(in, System.out);
```

Source code from [android](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-ssl).

Or RSA cipher:

```
public byte[] RSAEncrypt(final String plain) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException,
        InvalidKeyException, IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException {
    kpg = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
    kpg.initialize(1024);
    kp = kpg.genKeyPair();
    publicKey = kp.getPublic();
    privateKey = kp.getPrivate();

    cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, publicKey);
    encryptedBytes = cipher.doFinal(plain.getBytes());
    System.out.println("EEncrypted?????" + org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Hex.encodeHexString(encryptedBytes));
    return encryptedBytes;
}

public String RSADecrypt(final byte[] encryptedBytes) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException,
        InvalidKeyException, IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException {

    cipher1 = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");
    cipher1.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, privateKey);
    decryptedBytes = cipher1.doFinal(encryptedBytes);
    decrypted = new String(decryptedBytes);
    System.out.println("DDecrypted?????" + decrypted);
    return decrypted;
}
```

So the main question is: Which one should i use? for example, is Whatsapp using certificate or just RSA encryption?

Comment: Both of course. Is it supposed to be end-to-end encrypted (user-to-user)?

Comment: Ok thanks, Yes end-to-end or point-to-point encrypted.